# Why is my Logistic Regression output same for all inputs?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

I made a simple linear regression model with a simple .csv dataset that had 2 categories.

For reference, the dataset looks like a larger version of this

[image: What the dataset looks like]

Basically, it is a hobby classification dataset having two categories,

`'Name' and 'Category'.`

Now, I made a Logistic Regression model to classify the Hobbies based on their name.

Therefore, I took 'Name' as X and 'Category' as y.

Here is the simple code to train the model :

```py
X = data['Name']
X.values.reshape(1, -1)
y = data['Category']
y.values.reshape(1, -1)

model = LogisticRegression()

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

X_train = label_encoder.fit_transform(X_train)
y_train = label_encoder.fit_transform(y_train.ravel())

X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(256, -1)
y_train = np.array(y_train).reshape(256, -1)

model.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
```

Now, I made a simple list of 3 Names with diff categories for the purpose of testing.

```py
my_test = ['Sociology', 'Acting', 'Coding']

my_test = label_encoder.fit_transform(my_test)

my_test = np.array(my_test).reshape(3, -1)

model.predict(my_test)
```

But, this is the output

```py
array([1, 1, 1])
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the same output for all inputs I'm putting. Why is this happening ?

Comment: You've label-encoded the Names, so the (multiple) logistic regression is forced to treat them as ordered (alphabetically, I think?).  It's not surprising the model wouldn't be great.  Do you get different predictions for the other Names?

Comment: @BenReiniger I'm getting the same prediction for EVERYTHING

Comment: How do I apply Logistic Regression without label encoding ? Should I use OneHot Encoder ?

Comment: That would be better, yes. I just noticed that you `fit_transform` the test set, which is definitely a misstep, especially if your training set is ordered by category.  You should `fit_transform` the training X, not bother encoding the y, and use the now-fitted encoder to `transform` the test set.

Comment: oh ok.I'll try that